# How get free/busy slots of outlook Sub calendars, Image attached for reference

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, slots

I'm using Microsoft get/free busy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule API to get busy slots in the calendar but it only gives me slots for the main calendar. I need to find sub-calender slots too.
Anyone, please help.
[image]

I need Microsoft API which returns free/busy slots for sub-calendar for United States Holidays, Birthdays, Test calendars etc

Comment: the URL you posted does not work as you expect ... always doublecheck your post

Comment: HERE is API URL Get Free/Busy Schedule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule

Comment: please fix your post ... do not add important info into a comment

Comment: Exchange only tracks free busy on the primary calendar, for secondary calendars you would have to query the calendar directly (meaning you need read permissions) and create your own free busy logic.